# If $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence which does not tend to $0$, then there is an $N$ such that, for $n > N$, $a_n \neq 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Just learnt about Cauchy Sequences, this is a problem given by my analysis professor. I can visualize the problem, since an is Cauchy, after a certain threshold the terms of an will start to get cozier. Also every Cauchy sequence is convergent (in the set of reals) and an is approaching to some non-zero real. So, it makes sense that the members of the sequence will be non-zero after a certain threshold.

An approach given in the comment section by someone was that we can assume the negation of the conclusion, "for any $N$, $a_n=0$ for $n>N$" which would imply that $0$ is a limit point of this sequence (as $0$ occurs infinitely many times) and this would contradict the hypothesis that this sequence has a non-zero limit.

Are there other ways to prove this? How would the proof unfurl if I were to consider $a_n$ to be in an arbitrary metric space?

Comment: Show that if $a_n$ is Cauchy and for all $N\in\mathbb N$ there does exist an $n>N$ such that $a_n=0$, then $a_n$ tends to $0$. The triangle inequality will be useful (as always in analysis).

Comment: Hint : A cauchy sequence is convergent, say to the real number $L$. Now assume $L\ne 0$ , but $a_n=0$ for infinite many natural numbers $n$ and derive a contradiction.

Comment: Hint:a Cauchy sequence is convegent to a limit $l$ iff one of its subsequences converges to $l$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cauchy sequence doesn't converge to zero has all the same sign for values after a certain point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508279/cauchy-sequence-doesnt-converge-to-zero-has-all-the-same-sign-for-values-after)

Comment: @Peter thanks for the hint, if I assume an=0 for infinitely many naturals then that would imply that 0 is a limit point of this sequence which contradicts the hypothesis. 

What is the proving technique we're using here though?
There are 2 statements to my problem,
A:(an) does not tend to 0
B:there exists N s.t. for n>N, an is not equal to 0

I believe you are taking the negation of B to reach some contradiction,
that negation being "for any N, an=0 for all n>N". Am I right??

Comment: Yes, this is the approach I suggested using the mentioned negation. The negation is however not that there are eventually only zeros in the sequence, only that there are infinite many.

Comment: @Peter the negation of the statement "there exists N s.t. a[n]≠0 for all n>N" would be "for any N, there exists n>N s.t. a[n]=0"??

Comment: Yes, this is also a possible formulation and shows that the difference to $L$ is at least $|L|$ infinite many often , ruling out $L\ne 0$

Answer (score 1):

In an arbitrary metric space, the proof would go much the same as in the reals, except we can't say $a_n$ is equal or unequal to $0$, since the metric space might not contain $0$. Also, any technique using the convergence of the sequence to *some* point wouldn't work without some elbow grease (embeddeing the sequence in the closure of the metric space), since not all Cauchy sequences have to converge in an arbitrary metric space.

The statement should be modified like this:

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space, $x\in M$ and $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ a Cauchy sequence in $M$ which does not tend to $x$. Then there is $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $a_n\neq x$ for all $n>N$.

The proof works indirectly: If there were no such $N$, then the Cauchy sequence would converge to $x$.

Proof: We assume that for all $N\in\mathbb N$ there is an $n>N$ such that $a_n=x$. At the same time, we assume that $a_n$ is Cauchy, that is, for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is $M\in\mathbb N$ such that $d(a_m,a_n)<\varepsilon$ for all $n,m>M$.

We want to prove that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $d(a_n,x)<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$.

So let $\varepsilon>0$. Also let $M$ be such that $d(a_m,a_n)<\varepsilon$ for all $n,m>M$. This $M$ exists because $a_n$ is Cauchy. Now there exists $N>M$ such that $a_N=x$. Such $N$ exists because that's part of our assumptions. Now for all $n>N$ we have $d(a_N,a_n)<\varepsilon$. But since $a_N=x$, this just says that $d(x,a_n)<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$. But that just means that $a_n$ converges to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a Cauchy sequence which does not converge to zero.

Since it does not converge to zero, there exists $\varepsilon_0 > 0$ such that for every $n \geq 0$, there exists $k \geq n$ such that $|a_k| \geq \varepsilon_0$.

Since it is Cauchy, there exists $N \geq 0$ such that for every $m,n \geq N$, $|a_m-a_n| < \varepsilon_0$.

It now follows that $a_n \neq 0$ for every $n \geq N$, because if not, we would have that $|a_n| < \varepsilon_0$ for every $n \geq N$. However, this contradicts the claim in the second paragraph.

Comment: @TheoBendit The assertion in the second paragraph is correct - it is just the negation of the convergence to zero. In the example you give, $\varepsilon_0=1/2$ works.

Comment: Far more important : Do not give a complete answer to a question totally lacking context and effort ! Maybe, the above hints were already too much.

Comment: @Don My apologies, I did misread your condition.

Comment: I'm new to asking questions on MSE, my question got closed, how should I address my question such that it is aligned with this website's policy?

Comment: @AryanSaxena Hi! I'm sorry your question was closed. The usual requirements are (1) you should explain the context of your question (e.g. is it homework, part of a proof, a question you made up yourself, etc), and (2) you should show your attempt to solve it and where you got stuck. As you see, I'm not too strict with that and I hope my answer was useful :)

Comment: @Don grateful for the tips, highly appreciate it